# RelaxNG is expecting a namespace and I don't know why

Tags: php, validation, xhtml, relaxng

I am constructing an XHTML document like this *(in PHP)*:

```
$html = <<<"HEREDOC"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
</head>
<body>
$html
</body>
</html>
HEREDOC;
```

... and, as you can see, I *think* that I am properly specifying everything. But RelaxNG (*DOMDocument::RelaxNGValidate*) doesn't seem to think so:

```
Error 15: Expecting a namespace for element html on line 2
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: When the `<!DOCTYPE>` was reduced to `<!DOCTYPE html>` and an obligatory `<TITLE>` block was added to the `<HEAD>`, "https://html5.validator.nu" declared the resulting HTML to be **valid.**  Since I am calling a method of PHP's `DOMDocument` object, I of course looked for options in that object which might possibly be relevant, but found none so far.

Comment: Now I am ***totally*** confused!  The same message will appear, always saying `... element html ...`, even when the first node of the document is not a `<html>` tag.  It prints the line-number of whatever is the first node of the document *(for instance, if I remove the first three lines, to begin with `<body>`, and add four blank lines above it, the message will refer to "line 5" and will still say `element html`, not `element body`. So, it appears to be unmistakably complaining about something in the document, not (I think) the grammar, but the message now makes no sense at all to me.

Comment: If the error message does not change when you make significant changes to what you think is the input, sometimes the reason is that that is not in fact the input.   You don't show how you made a DOMDocument object out of the string HEREDOC; how certain are you that it did what you expected?  If you call DOM methods for examining the local name and namespace of the root element, what do they show?